# OnClick no se ejecuta despues del OnClientClick

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, webservice

Tengo un formulario con un botón, cuando piso el botón (este botón en realidad lo uso para varias cosas cambiandole el nombre y usando flags en el método que define el click) este ejecuta el JavaScript en el cliente pero nunca llega al code-behind ni en el Page_Load ni en el evento del Click, sin embargo el JavaScript si se ejecuta.

Mi botón:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnCierre" Text="Iniciar Cierre" Style="width: 150px" Enabled="false" OnClick="btnCierre_Click" OnClientClick="return StartCierre();" UseSubmitBehavior="true" />
```

Mi JS:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function StartCierre() {
        if (document.getElementById("<%= btnCierre.ClientID %>").value == "Aceptar") {
            document.getElementById("<%= AnimacionDeCarga.ClientID %>").style.visibility = 'visible';
            document.getElementById("<%= btnDownSistema.ClientID %>").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("<%= btnCierre.ClientID %>").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("<%= btnCancel.ClientID %>").disabled = true;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Todo el JS se ejecuta incluso el retorno del true pero en el code-behind puedo poner breakpoints en todo el código y nunca llega a ninguno.

Cuando uso el botón para otras cosas si funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando ejecutas la funcion javascript, desactivas el buton lo que previene que se ejecute el evento del servidor:

```
function StartCierre() {
        if (document.getElementById("<%= btnCierre.ClientID %>").value == "Aceptar") {
            //...
            document.getElementById("<%= btnCierre.ClientID %>").disabled = true;
          //...
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Tienes que dejar el buton activo para que el evento se pueda ejecutar:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function StartCierre() {
        if (document.getElementById("<%= btnCierre.ClientID %>").value == "Aceptar") {
            document.getElementById("<%= AnimacionDeCarga.ClientID %>").style.visibility = 'visible';
            document.getElementById("<%= btnDownSistema.ClientID %>").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("<%= btnCancel.ClientID %>").disabled = true;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Pero si necesitas desactivarlo, cuando se ejecute el evento del servidor, desactivas el boton:

```
private void btnCierre_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //...
   //...
  btnCierre.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Tiene mucho sentido... pero necesito ese botón deshabilitado, alguna sugerencia? en realidad necesito que se vea deshabilitado nada mas...

Comment: Entonces  desactiva el boton en el evento del servidor no en el javascript.

Comment: Mira la respuesta actualizada

Comment: Claro, el problema de desactivarlo en el servidor es que se hace el cambio cuando se refresque la pagina. Yo deshabilito mis 3 botones porque el proceso es muy largo (20min) y lo hago por JS para hacer el cambio antes de que entre en proceso el servidor. incluso, a penas el proceso largo termina actualizo la pagina con una configuración de botones de una vez